Integral in terms of Hypergeometric function
Consider the integral $$ I = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 (1+c^2v^2)^{-s}u^{1-2s}(1-uv)^{s-1}dudv$$
where $c>0$ is some constant and $0<s<1$. Clearly the integral is absolutely integrable (Two singularities present at $u=0$ and at $u=v=1$, both of which are weak) and my goal is figure out an exact solution of this integral (Preferably in terms of Hypergeom, and can also be in terms of Kampé de Fériet function). This is what I have done until now: Using Binomial expansion $$(1+x)^{-\alpha} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+\alpha-1}{n}(-1)^nx^n \text{ and } \frac{1}{n+z} = \frac{\Gamma(n+z)}{\Gamma(n+z+1)} = \frac{(z)_n}{z (z+1)_n},$$
I got
\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^1\int_0^1 \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{m+s-1}{m}\binom{n+s-2}{n}(-c^2)^m(-1)^nv^{2m+n}u^{n+1-2s}dudv\\
&= \sum_{n,m} \frac{\Gamma(m+s)}{\Gamma(s) m!}\frac{\Gamma(n+s-1)}{\Gamma(s-1) n!}\frac{(-c^2)^m(-1)^n}{(2m+n+1)(n+2-2s)},\\
&= \frac{1}{2(1-s)}\sum_{n,m} \frac{(s)_m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_m}\frac{(s-1)_n(2-2s)_n(2m+1)_n}{(3-2s)_n(2m+2)_n}\cdot \frac{(-c^2)^m}{m!} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}
Not sure how to proceed after this. We can first sum it over index $n$, to obtain $$ I = \frac{1}{2(1-s)}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(s)_m\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_m}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_m} {}_{3}F_{2}\left([s-1,2-2s,2m+1],[3-2s,2m+2];-1\right) \frac{(-c^2)^m}{m!}. $$
but it doesn't feel useful.
Context: I am searching for a closed form solution of this integral because I have a numerical algorithm to compute double integrals of this form. A closed form solution will help me check the accuracy of my algorithm.
Edit : You may take $c=1$ if the constant is bothering you. If a closed form is not possible, is there a way to evaluate this sum such that we get all 16 digits numerically in Matlab?

Using only Mathematica:
$$\int _0^1\int _0^1\left(1+c^2 v^2\right)^{-s} u^{1-2 s} (1-u v)^{s-1}dvdu=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int _0^1\int _0^1\mathcal{M}_c\left[\left(1+c^2
   v^2\right)^{-s} u^{1-2 s} (1-u v)^{s-1}\right](q)dvdu\right](c)=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{u^{1-2 s} v^{-q} (1-u v)^{-1+s}
   \Gamma \left(\frac{q}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right)}{2 \Gamma (s)}dvdu\right](c)=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^1
   \frac{u^{1-2 s} v^{-q} (1-u v)^{-1+s} \Gamma \left(\frac{q}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right)}{2 \Gamma (s)} \, du\right) \,
   dv\right](c)=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\int_0^1 \frac{v^{-2-q+2 s} B_v(2-2 s,s) \Gamma \left(\frac{q}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right)}{2
   \Gamma (s)} \, dv\right](c)=\mathcal{M}_q^{-1}\left[\frac{(-1)^{2 s} 2^{-q} e^{-i \pi  s} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (q-s) \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right)}{(1+q-2 s) \Gamma \left(\frac{1+q}{2}\right)}-\frac{e^{i \pi  s} \pi  \csc (\pi  s) \Gamma \left(\frac{q}{2}\right)
   \Gamma \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right)}{2 \left(1+e^{2 i \pi  s}\right) (-1-q+2 s) \Gamma (2-s) \Gamma (-1+2 s)}-\frac{2^{-q} e^{-i \pi  s+i \pi  (q+s)}
   \sqrt{\pi } \csc (\pi  q) \Gamma (q-s) \Gamma \left(-\frac{q}{2}+s\right) \sin (\pi  s)}{(1+q-2 s) \Gamma
   \left(\frac{1+q}{2}\right)}\right](c)=\frac{2^{2-2 s} c^{-2 s} e^{i \pi  s} \pi ^{3/2} \csc (\pi  s) \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},s;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{c^2}\right)}{\left(1+e^{2 i \pi  s}\right) \Gamma (2-s) \Gamma
   \left(-\frac{1}{2}+s\right)}+\frac{(-1)^{2 s} 2^{1-2 s} c^{-2 s} e^{-i \pi  s} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (s) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}+s;-\frac{1}{c^2}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+s\right)}+\frac{\,
   _4F_3\left(1,\frac{3}{2}-s,1-\frac{s}{2},\frac{3}{2}-\frac{s}{2};\frac{3}{2},2-s,\frac{5}{2}-s;-\frac{1}{c^2}\right)}{2 c^2 (-3+2 s)}-\frac{2^{-1+4
   s} c^{-2 s} \sqrt{\pi } \csc (2 \pi  s) \Gamma (s)^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}+s;-\frac{1}{c^2}\right) \sin (\pi  s)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-2
   s\right) \Gamma (4 s)}-\frac{i 2^{1-2 s} c^{-2 s} \sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (s) \,
   _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{s}{2},\frac{s}{2};\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}+s;-\frac{1}{c^2}\right) \sin (\pi  s)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{2}+s\right)}-\frac{2^{-2 s} \Gamma (1-s)^2 \,
   _3F_2\left(1-s,\frac{1}{2}-\frac{s}{2},1-\frac{s}{2};\frac{3}{2}-s,2-s;-\frac{1}{c^2}\right) \tan (\pi  s)}{c \Gamma (3-2 s)}$$
Where ${M}_q^{-1}(c)$ is Inverse Mellin Transfrom and  ${M}_c{(q)}$ is Mellin Transfrom
Mathematica code:
(2^(2 - 2 s) c^(-2 s) E^(I \[Pi] s) \[Pi]^(3/2) Csc[\[Pi] s] Hypergeometric2F1[1/2, s, 3/ 2, -(1/c^2)])/((1 + E^(2 I \[Pi] s)) Gamma[ 2 - s] Gamma[-(1/2) + s]) + ((-1)^(2 s) 2^(1 - 2 s) c^(-2 s) E^(-I \[Pi] s) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[s] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2 + s/2, s/2}, {3/2,  1/2 + s}, -(1/c^2)])/Gamma[1/2 + s] +  HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 3/2 - s, 1 - s/2, 3/2 - s/2}, {3/2, 2 - s,  5/2 - s}, -(1/c^2)]/(2 c^2 (-3 + 2 s)) - ( 2^(-1 + 4 s) c^(-2 s) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Csc[2 \[Pi] s] Gamma[ s]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2 + s/2, s/2}, {3/2, 1/2 + s}, -(1/ c^2)] Sin[\[Pi] s])/(Gamma[1/2 - 2 s] Gamma[4 s]) - ( I 2^(1 - 2 s) c^(-2 s) Sqrt[\[Pi]] Gamma[s] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1/2 + s/2, s/2}, {3/2,  1/2 + s}, -(1/c^2)] Sin[\[Pi] s])/Gamma[1/2 + s] - ( 2^(-2 s) Gamma[ 1 - s]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1 - s, 1/2 - s/2, 1 - s/2}, {3/2 - s,  2 - s}, -(1/c^2)] Tan[\[Pi] s])/(c Gamma[3 - 2 s])

Which version was Mathematica did you use? I have version 13.1 which couldn't simplify the integral.

@Sam .Version 14.0.

I am not aware of the notation $B_v$, is this the beta integral?

@Sam  $B_v$ is incomplete beta function. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html

Aah. I see. Is there a identity which solves the integral $\int_0^1 v^{-2-q+2s}B_v(2-2s,s) dv$

The integral should be a real number. I believe there are further cancellation in the expression which will remove the imaginary terms.

@Sam See here:https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Beta3/21/01/02/01/

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is not an answer
From a computation point of view, why not to stay with
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac { B_v(2(1- s),s)} {v^{2(1- s)} \left(1+c^2 v^2\right)^s }\,dv$$ which does not seem to make too much problems with numerical integration.
If required, I think that a series expansion of
$$\frac { B_v(2(1- s),s)} {v^{2(1- s)} }=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,v^n$$ could be useful.

I am not aware of the definition of $B_v$. Is this the beta integral?

Also, I am not sure if this will be numerically efficient for values to s close to $1$. We might require a large of terms in the series expansion for a good approximation.

@Sam. I agree with you. I would stay with the first solution.
